# If a string is found in any of the columns, return true in r

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I'm trying to return a TRUE/FALSE value when a part of a string is present in the list of column names for a dataframe. How would I accomplish this? I'll attach what I tried to do which after doing some research probably wouldn't work. My thought is that "%" would work like the like operator.

```
"criteria.%" %in% colnames(CriteriaList)
```

I don't actually want "%" in the string.

Comment: Try `any(grepl("criteria.%", colnames(CriteriaList), fixed = TRUE))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by `any(grepl("criteria.", colnames(CriteriaList), fixed = T)`
You could also use the `%like%` operator.